# How to enable bluetooth on my Lifebook LH531?

Tags: bluetooth, adapter

I have lifebook lh531. it says bluetooth adapter not installed. how do i enable bluetooh on this machine. it has a sticker "bluetooth" I am using ubuntu 11.10 and do "hcitool dev" it gives nothing at the prompt. sudo commands starts and restarts the bluetooth. No indication on the panel

Answer (score 2):

If your lifebook is hardware compatable then:
Ubuntu 11.04 Install via the command line

```
sudo apt-get install bluez python-gobject python-dbus
```

python-gobject and python-dbus are needed for the python scripts bluez-simple-agent and bluez-test-device to work.

Discover the hciX location of the dongle with:

```
hcitool dev

Devices:
        hci0    00:11:95:00:1A:CF
```

For additional information see this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bluez is already the newest version.
python-dbus is already the newest version.
python-gobject is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I have tried  the replies are as under Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bluez is already the newest version.
python-dbus is already the newest version.
python-gobject is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pro-hq@prohq-LIFEBOOK-LH531:~$ hcitool dev
Devices: